# Aspect (simple, perfect and progressive): What are the differences?

Tags: tenses, aspect

Could you please explain to me the differences between the simple, progressive and perfect aspects.

"Simple aspect" means completed action (action starts and finishes) but I don't really understand the fine details.

For example, with these sentences:

> It usually rains in the fall.
>   He smokes 15 cigarettes a day.
>   I slept for a long time yesterday.

Here's what I understand: if I didn't complete sleeping I should use "I was sleeping". If it doesn't stop raining we can't say "it is finished". Is that correct?

For continuous aspect, duration is an important factor – but how?

For example:

> She is wearing a jacket.

Normally "to wear" action is completed but we can use here present continuous aspect.

Another example:

> She has been wearing the same jacket for 3 days.

and why can't I use continuous aspect here?

> I have cleaned my room.

It means that my room is clean now. Action is finished but why can't I say "I *have been cleaning* room" like "They *have been playing* in the mud"? Action is completed but we don't care here about completed, we are caring about duration, why?

Answer (score 3):

Aspect does not refer to a difference in the things described. It refers *entirely* to how the speaker is choosing to refer to the events on that occasion: specifically, on the temporal relationship between the events and other events or points in time.

*I was sleeping* is focussing on the continuing state (in the past) of my being asleep. It can refer to precisely the same event as *I slept* or *I have slept*: the choice is in what we are saying about the event.

In English, for most verbs we use the so-called present continuous to talk about events which are happening at this moment, irrespective of how long they are continuing: *She is wearing a jacket* usually talks about the fact that at this moment she has a jacket, and says nothing about how long or how often she does so. For most verbs, we use the simple present only for habitual or universal claims: *She wears a jacket* talks about her habitual apparel. (It may or may not be true that *she is wearing a jacket* at this moment, but this does not affect whether *She wears a jacket* is true).

Verbs of perception and mental state usually do not behave in this way, and are used in the simple present (*I see*, *I feel*, *I remember*). They can be used in the continuous, but this is "marked" as linguists say, and expresses a specific meaning: focussing on the immediate currency of the state or perception. But again they do not express a different situation, just a different way of referring to it, with a different focus.

In the past, there are two more options - the perfect (*I have seen*) and the perfect continuous (*I have been seeing*). Again, the difference is in what we are focussing on, not in the events described. In *I have cleaned my room*, we are focussing on the present relevance of the activity, and on the action being completed. But we certainly can say *I have been cleaning my room*, about the same activity, but with a different focus.

One way to look at this is by considering what questions they might answer.

*What have you done today?  I have cleaned my room*.

*Where were you at 2:30 this afternoon? I was cleaning my room*.

*How did you spend the afternoon? I have been cleaning my room*.

Comment: An eponymous answer :)

Comment: Good answer, I like the sample Q&As illustrating the past tense. I'd just like to mention something about the past progressive.  One might think its point-in-time nature would make it uncommon (_At 2am, I was sleeping._). But it appears frequently because of constructs like “an action was happening, when some event occurred”. _I was sleeping when the telephone rang._  This conversation goes from present continuous to past continuous: _Ring, ring. Hello? What are you doing? I_ was _sleeping!_

Comment: A follow-up question, if I may.  What aspect is “_I had been cleaning my room_”?  (Rather than “have been”.)

Comment: It's perfect continuous, but relative to a past time rather than a present time.

Comment: thank you for your answer can you please give me more detail about "action completed mean"

Comment: and present perfect focusing on the present relevance of the activity and on the action being completed.So
i have cleaned my car means my car is clean if you dont believe come and check it or i cleaned it 5 days ago and still clean or ?how do you connect the present and result of action
you have been crying (your eyes still red).The action is completed but present relevance of the activity is still valid. if i say that "you have cried ?" is it wrong i cant catch differences could you please give me more details

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Good pun. But the author is eponymous, not the work.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock: You must know better than the dictionaries I use. For instance, {[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eponymous)} says that 'eponymous' may be applied to either the author or the work. But you've probably done more research on the subject than their corpus-investigating professional lexicographers: **eponymous** adj
1. (of a person) being the person after whom a literary work, film, etc, is named: the eponymous heroine in the film of Jane Eyre.
**2. (of a literary work, film, etc) named after its central character or creator** [bolding mine]

Comment: ... Of course, I stretched the second sense.

Comment: Yes, it's in that dictionary now. It is another example of backwards usage becoming so common as to be "accepted", thus ruining a perfectly good word by making it an auto-antonym.  I expect the same thing to happen soon with the bass-ackward usage "A is comprised of B, C and D" (to mean "composed of) and the baffling usage of "substitute A with B" (to mean either  "replace A with B" or "replace B with A", two contradictory actions.) 

By the way, do you wonder if anyone else caught your clever wordplay? Including the target himself?  Maybe he's heard it before.

Comment: @Colin Fine How did you spend the afternoon? I have been cleaning my room. Is it possible the cleaning of the room is completed, but the focus is on the activity?

Comment: @anouk: yes. In the question _How did you spend the afternoon?_, the questioner is treating it as a completed activity, so the [cooperative principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle) makes a simple past the most likely answer. But the answerer could choose to focus on the present relevance (_I've cleaned my room_), or the continuing activity (_I was cleaning my room_) or both (_I've been cleaning my room_).

Comment: @ Colin Fine So it is possible to say: "I have been cleaning my room" when your room is clean now but you choose to focus on the activity, not the result?

Comment: @anouk. Yes. "I have been cleaning my room" _suggests_ that you may not have finished, but it does not necessarily imply that. I'm not sure that it focuses so much on the activity as on the continuing nature of the activity.

Comment: @ Colin Fine Just to be clear about this: I can say "I have been cleaning my room" not just when I have finished the activity of cleaning my room, but also when the room has been cleaned, meaning the room is clean now?  I am just putting the focus on the ongoing nature of the activity, even though I am no longer doing the activity?

Comment: @Anouk. Yes. I have perhaps overstated the idea of _focus_: If I say "I have been cleaning out my room, and I've found this old photo", the focus is on the photo, not the cleaning; but the implication is that the cleaning took some while - maybe the whole afternoon, or perhaps it was over several days. I might also say "I've cleaned out my room and found this photograph", and then I am not putting any emphasis at all on how long it did or didn't take. These distinctions are very subtle.

Comment: @ Colin Fine Thank you, But can you say "I have been cleaning" when you have recently stopped cleaning?

Comment: @anouk, yes, you can. The _have_ means "I am choosing to treat the events I am describing as having some present relevance, though what exactly that present relevance means can be very variable". The _be -ing_ means "I am choosing to treat the events I am describing as having lasted over a period".

Comment: @Colin Fine By "the continuing nature of the activity" you mean "having lasted over a period of time". It doesn't necessarily mean it is still going on at this moment.  Correct?

Comment: @anouk - I am not going to continue this discussion.